# How to use group by and having count in Linq

Tags: c#, linq

I am having trouble trying to convert the following query from SQL to Linq, in particular with the having count and group by parts of the query:

```
select ProjectID
from ProjectAssociation

where TeamID in ( select TeamID 
                  from [User]
                  where UserID in (4))
group by ProjectID
having COUNT(TeamID) = (select distinct COUNT(TeamID)
                        from [User]
                        where UserID in (4))
```

Any advice on how to do so would be much appreciated.

Comment: Are you really always going to be doing in "4" ? Or do you mean UserID ==4? 

Let me know and i will help you rewrite this.And maybe you should also describe what you are trying to accomplish with your query, because there could be a better way to do it

Answer (score 3):

var groups = from pa in ProjectAssociation
       let teamIds = User.Where(u => u.UserID == 4).Select(u => u.TeamID)
       where teamIds.Contains(pa.TeamID)
       group pa by pa.ProjectID;

```
var result = from g in groups
   let count = User.Where(u => u.UserID == 4).Select(u => u.TeamID).Distinct().Count()
   where g.Count() == count
   select g.Key;
```

Or maybe more optimal:

```
var teamIds = User.Where(u => u.UserID == 4).Select(u => u.TeamID).AsEnumerable();
var groups = ProjectAssociation.Where(pa => teamIds.Contains(pa.TeamID)
   .GroupBy(pa => pa.ProjectID);
var result = from g in groups
       let count = teamIds.Distinct().Count()
       where g.Count() == count
       select g.Key;
```

By the way, i think that by

```
select distinct COUNT(TeamID)
```

you meant:

```
select COUNT(distinct TeamID)
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a tool (cheap) that will convert queries like this for you. It's called Linqer. I own a  copy and have found that it's able to convert event the most complex of queries. The URL is `http://www.sqltolinq.com/`

It's not free, but it's pretty inexpensive and has a 30 day trial.

Comment: Thank you for you response Randy. I have tied this software, although it was unable to convert the having count clause, I was able to use the code that it did convert and resolve my issue.

Comment: couldn't get this software to work; it wants to generate some data files, and would always lock up on trying to do so against a SQL 2008 database.